# Why validators saying Error in Stylesheet media screen handleid

Tags: css, validation

my question is very simple.
The w3 validator say's 
[image]

And I don't know why. Im using a code provide from stackoverflow users answers.
Someone can help me or fix this?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, handheld">
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the screenshot, `handheld` media type is deprecated. Code changes and evolves, just because you see something in an SO answer, doesn't mean it will work as intended forever. Use this instead:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

I couldn't find documented explanation, but my guess is that css media queries are the modern day solution that's replacing `handheld` media type. Furthermore, popular html & css frameworks are technically "handheld-first" or rather "mobile-first".

Comment: You can also add this to `media`: `<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 640px)" href="foobar.css" />`. Although you should program mobile first, but that's a different discussion.